# Guice doesn't inject morphia returned object

Tags: java, reflection, dependency-injection, guice, morphia

I have a class that identifies a field with @Inject. I persist this object to MongoDB using morphia. When the time comes to get the object back, I execute a query, like this:

```
MorphiaVersionedPerson versionedPerson =  ds.find(entityClazz).filter("published.name", name).get();
```

As I understand it, Morphia will use the no arg constructor to create an instance of that object and then it uses reflection to populate the field values.

The value that Guice should @Inject is null. I know that Guice also uses reflection, but in this case, guice doesn't create the object. Morphia creates the object.

I suppose I could try to get the injector in my DAO and do something like this:

```
injector.injectMembers(versionedPerson )
```

However, getting the injector seems a bit off. Is there some other way to get morhpia and Guice to interact in this situation? How can I get guice to @Inject necessary elements into a morhpia created object?

Answer (score 1):

In this case there is no other way but to use the Injector. Therefore it shouldn't feel unnatural to use it directly.

You can use the #injectMembers in DAO but as you pointed out that feels a bit off. And it is. Also in this way Guice AOP will not work. Guice needs to be the creator of the object in order for AOP to work.

What I'd do is integrate Guice into Morphia. Haven't used Morphia but a quick look revealed that there is an upcoming Guice extension for Morphia.

https://github.com/jmkgreen/morphia/blob/master/guice-plug/src/main/java/com/github/jmkgreen/morphia/ext/guice/GuiceExtension.java

In the bootstrapping code I'd do something along the lines of

```
Morphia m = injector.getInstance(Morphia.class);
new GuiceExtension(m, injector);
```

If you'd write this extension yourself you use the Injector directly.

OT: [Do you really need the DAO? Food for thought.](http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html-single/index.html#architecture)

Comment: Also make sure that Morphia is bound to a single instance by your Guice module, otherwise Guice will create another one that has not been extended to use the injector.